# How to convert date format in json response to string format in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, rest

I have set a column to column type "Date" and the json response from listData.svc for this column is in this format `"Created": "/Date(1377683175000)/"` , can someone suggest how to convert this format to string?

I have tried `new Date(Time).toLocaleString`  (Time is the variable that hold the date/time field) but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing javascript for SharePoint and can use its javascript libraries then it might be a good idea to be using standart approach which take care of all the rest

```
var date = new Date();
var arg = { date: date };
var str = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.serialize(arg);// "{"date":"\/Date(1377757755979)\/"}"
var newObject = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize(str);
var newDate = newObject.date; // Date {Thu Aug 29 2013 10:29:15 GMT+0400}
```

The class is a part of [Microsoft Ajax Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163300.aspx) so it is a good idea to use it whenever you want to communicate with standart Microsoft Web Services.

Comment: Do I have to load microsoftajax.js or it is included out of the box with SharePoint 2010?

Comment: Included already.

Answer (score 0):

```
        private static DateTime ConvertJsonTimestamp(double jsonTime)
    {

        var baseTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

        return baseTime.AddSeconds(jsonTime);

    }
```

pass in your Time variable to this method and you will get a .net date back. There are other methods, but most requires som third party library like Newtonsoft

Answer (score 0):

As part of .Net Framework at least two options are available:

- `Deserialize` method from
  [System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)
- `ReadObject` method from
  [System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx)

### Example

```
string dateString = @"""\/Date(1377683175000)\/""";
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var date = serializer.Deserialize<DateTime>(dateString);  //returns {28.8.2013 9:46:15}
```